# Cannot use interface or class from another local dependency module

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, dependencies

```cpp
Parent Project 
|
|---pom.xml
|
|---Module A
|          |---pom.xml
|
|---Module B
           |---pom.xml
```

- A and B was declared as Modules of parent.
- Parent was declared as < parent > of A and B.
- A depends on B, in A's pom.xml:

```xml
<dependency>
     <groupId>abc.b</groupId>
     <artifactId>b</artifactId>
     <version>0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

I'm using an interface from B in A, however A cannot find the interface:
[ERROR] : cannot find the symbol/package.

Did I miss something for dependency ?

https://github.com/jianfeipan/ParisTraining/tree/master/server

Parent ： server

A: restapi

B: classService

Comment: What are the `groupId`s of Parent and module A?

Comment: Did you alread build module B? Has that interface newly been added to module B? If so that would mean module B is still under development so the problem might be that you're not using a snapshot version and thus Maven doesn't know to look for updates on that dependency.

Comment: If all these are included in the same IntelliJ IDEA project, module B might not need to be built for module A to resolve the dependency. But probably the maven panel should be refreshed.

Comment: Also make sure the parent module lists all the child modules.

Comment: @UdithGunaratna groupId for A is like : abc.a and abc.b for b. abc.parent for parent

Comment: @Thomas Module B was build and installed successfully, I tried refresh maven but it didn't work

Comment: @Andrey Yes, the parent lists the A,B modules.

Comment: Why is the group id different for the modules and the parent? Normally the group id would be the same, e.g. `abc`, and the artifact id is what's different. To emphasize the meaning of the group id: in ivy it's called "organization"

Comment: @Thomas yes, you are right, I renamed them. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I should add packages... my classes are directly under java/.